# Is pushing code from MacOS the same as pushing from Windows ? ( C# )

Tags: c#, windows, azure, macos, github

I know it's an easy answer to answer but after searching online there's no trusted source that validated this for me.

If I created a repository from a Windows machine and had to code from a MacOS machine for some function or just because that's what I had at the moment, if I push to the repository from the Mac, will it had extra "Mac files" or "Mac compilation" files that could break the solution when pulled on the windows machine or published to the Azure Server ?

Thank you

Comment: It's rather a strange question. In each commits you are of full control on which files/changes are included, so you have no clue on what are "Mac files"?

Comment: Generally speaking, a Git repository stores **source code**  (i.e. text files). It is up to the platform using that source code to properly interpret it, not Git.

Comment: I see, so it won't add extra "platform files" that would confuse another machine pulling the code right ?

Comment: Or alternatively, a cross platform repo like https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvaloniaILSpy/tree/master/ILSpy does contain Mac only files such as `Info.plist` (and many others), but well organized source code like that can compile successfully everywhere.

Comment: Oh I see @LexLi, I have the same for my Xamarin.Forms code but I wasn't sure for an ASP.NET Core code for example

Comment: There are platform-specific files, but C# code is C# code; NET Core is cross-platform, so.

Comment: An ASP.NET Core project rarely has platform specific code/files (BTW, web projects are better done on Mac or Linux, or you won't notice file name casing issues until it is too late).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a .gitignore for macOS such as the example given by github below:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/macOS.gitignore

The presence of the files won't be destructive to your cause, however they would be annoying to have to manually remove. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files